# How do I unlock leveling up?

Tags: elden-ring

Based on my conversations with the first real NPC I came across (And my experience with previous "Souls" games), I assume I need to find a Maidan to level up. In previous games, the leveling NPC was tied to a specific location. Given the open world nature of Elden Ring, I'm a little concerned about going off in the completely wrong direction, and missing the ability to level up for quite a while.

**How do I unlock leveling up?**

Comment: Posted this question and answer since I'm sure I'm not the only one that's looking for a spoiler free answer to the root concern here, which was that I was hesitant to explore or tackle too many tough encounters before I unlocked leveling up, and was worried that going off in some random direction would just be a "Dead end" as far as unlocking the leveling is concerned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's impossible to miss the ability to level up, since unlike in previous games, it's not tied to a single location. Just keep playing, exploring whichever direction you desire, and you'll unlock leveling up.

The exact criteria for leveling up are:

> To unlock leveling up, you just need to visit 3 different Sites of Grace. Once you visit the third Site of Grace, a cutscene will play and you'll be able to level up. Additionally, Sites of Grace located in the mini dungeons do not contribute to this total (including the tutorial one).

[Source IGN](https://www.ign.com/wikis/elden-ring/How_to_Level_Up_in_Elden_Ring)

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. A recent speedrun (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anm0CPYpGcM) triggers that cutscene by resting at the Stormgate site of grace without resting at any other site of grace in the game. That may be an alternate condition.